# ¿Por qué al pasar el parámetro UTM utm_medium=referral aparece como utm_mediureferral en el navegador?

Tags: php, javascript, navegador-web, parametros

¿Por qué ocurre esta cosa tan extraña de que el parámetro **utm_medium=referral** se queda como acortado o contraído como **utm_mediureferral** en la barra de direcciones del navegador?

¿Algún experto podría explicarme a qué se debe esto?

*Los parámetros utm los creo en el código javascript que genera una url dinámica:

```js
...'<a href="' + url + '?s='+ texto +'&utm_source='+ location.host +'&utm_medium=referral&...
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  e indica qué código estás generado y cómo lo generas.

Comment: Ya di más detalle del código en javascript..